# ran insecure content from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dijit/form/Form.xd.js

Tags: dojo

I am running my site under certificate. The certificate is valid but it still give me this errors when i try to load my site using https. I checked my layout file and i m referring to https entries on google apis site.

Here is an example of my layout.cshtml

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojox/form/resources/BusyButton.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojox/widget/Wizard/Wizard.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    djConfig = {
        parseOnLoad: false,
        isDebug: false,
        baseUrl: "/Scripts/dojo/rpost/",
        // modulePaths: { rpost: "/Scripts/dojo/rpost" }
    };
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require('dijit.form.Form');
    dojo.require('dijit.form.CheckBox');
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
    dojo.require('dijit.form.ValidationTextBox');
    dojo.require('dojox.form.BusyButton');
    dojo.require('dojox.form.DropDownSelect');
    dojo.require('dijit.form.DropDownButton');
    dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
    dojo.require('dijit.form.NumberTextBox');
    dojo.require('dijit.form.NumberSpinner');
    dojo.require('dijit.form.DateTextBox');
    dojo.require('dijit.form.SimpleTextarea');
    dojo.require("dijit.Menu");
    dojo.require('dijit.Dialog');
    dojo.require("dijit.TooltipDialog");
    dojo.require('dijit.MenuSeparator');
    dojo.require('dijit.MenuItem');
    dojo.require('dijit.layout.TabContainer');
    dojo.require('dijit.PopupMenuItem');
    dojo.require('dijit.Declaration');
    dojo.require('dojox.layout.TableContainer');
    dojo.require('rpost.AutocompleteReadStore');
    dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-traverse");
    dojo.require('rpost.ConfirmationDialog');
    dojo.require('dojo.parser');

    dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            dojo.query('.delayUI').forEach(function (el) {
                // dijit.byNode(el).fadeIn({ delay: 100 }).play();
            });
        }, dijit.defaultDuration + 10);
        // do something();

        @if (IsSectionDefined("GridLayout"))
        { 
            @RenderSection("GridLayout")
        }

        dojo.parser.parse();
    });
</script>
```

Can please anyone advice me what to do? 
Really appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.

Add these below lines in your djConfig

```
modulePaths: {
                "dojo": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo",
                "dijit": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dijit",
                "dojox": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojox" 
            }
```

This should do it.

Thanks,
Vivek